# Cast a string to a name of a web label

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

HI, using vs2008 and building a web app. On a asp page called blackjack.aspx, I have four labels with id of lbBJTStatusP1  lbBJTStatusP2 lbBJTStatusP3 lbBJTStatusP4.

I want to address those labels in a single sub by casting the casting two strings into the   control name, so that string lbBJTStatusP & "1" would refer to lbBJTStatusP1.This is done on the code behind page.

So far I have tried this but with no success. boxct refers to either "1" "2" "3" or "4".

```
DirectCast(blackjack.Controls.Find("lbBJTStatusP" & boxct, True)(0), Label).BackColor = stoodcolor
```

Can it be done and if so how. Thanks for all and any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "cast" a string to a specific instance of a control.

What you *can* do is use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx): that accepts a string, searches (one level deep, not more) for a control with that name and returns it. The method returns a `Control`, so you might need to cast it to `Label`.

Answer (score 1):

I have labels named lblqu01ex - lblqu10ex. I set the text value through coding as follows.
`for i = 1 to 10`
`ex = "lbl" & IIf(i = 10, "qu10", "qu0" & i) & "ex"`
`DirectCast(FindControl(ex), Label).Text = 2*100/i`
`next`

Its work.